# Sort by character length but don't want filter

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

**Wants to sort reviews with comment length <= 250 and >= 50**

All short or long reviews should be at the end..currently i have to filter them... but this is not what I wants to have

current query

```
select
c.id,
c.name,
DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d %b %Y') as date_new,
r.ratings,
c.comments,
ROUND((r.ratings_sum / r.ratings_qty),1) as total_rating
from
commentsAS c , rating AS r , id_script i
where
c.pid = i.sub_cat_id
AND i.cat_id = 118
AND r.reviewid = c.id
AND c.published = '1'
AND LENGTH(c.comments) <= 250
AND LENGTH(c.comments) >= 50
ORDER BY c.created DESC
```

I don't want filter them with below

```
AND LENGTH(c.comments) <= 250
AND LENGTH(c.comments) >= 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this simply using a boolean expression:

```
order by ( length(c.comments) < 50 or length(c.comments) > 250) desc
```

MySQL treats booleans in a numeric context as integers, with true as 1.

An alternative formulation is even shorter:

```
order by (length(c.comments) between 50 and 249)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN LENGTH(C.comments) > 250 OR LENGTH(C.comments) < 50 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: doesn't seems like working... sorted by with short comments in middle

Answer (score 0):

If you use a new Version of MariaDB you can use a virtual persitent column. If you insert or change date they count direct new feld. You can also use a index or composite index on it.

**Alter the table**

```
ALTER TABLE comments
ADD COLUMN l INT AS (LENGTH(`comments`)) PERSISTENT,
ADD KEY  (`comments`);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.name,
  DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d %b %Y') as date_new,
  r.ratings, c.comments,
  ROUND((r.ratings_sum / r.ratings_qty),1) as total_rating
  FROM commentsAS c , rating AS r , id_script i
where
  c.pid = i.sub_cat_id
  AND i.cat_id = 118
  AND r.reviewid = c.id
  AND c.published = '1'
  AND c.l between 50 AND 250
  ORDER BY c.created DESC;
```